# Array Reversal - HackerRank problem - Using C language

Tags: arrays, c

I am doing a problem in HackerRank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reverse-array-c/problem

My idea is store the value of a[0] to one variable( store), then assign a[0] = a[end], then a[end] = store, after that I will move to a[1] and a[end -1].

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num, *arr, i;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    arr = (int*) malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        scanf("%d", arr + i);
    }


    /* Write the logic to reverse the array. */
    int start = 0, end = num - 1;
    int store;
    while ((start != end) || (start != (end+1)))
    {
        store = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = store;
        start++;
        end--;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
    
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

However, my code result returns nothing. Can anyone help me point out the problem in my code? I truly appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `(start != end) || (start != (end+1))` will always be true because `end != (end+1)` and `start` will never be equal to both of `end` and `end+1` at the same time.

It should be `(start != end) && (start != (end+1))`.